# Django 3.1.5 and Channels 3.0.3 websocket problem

Tags: python, django, channel

I am migrating an app to Django 3.1.5 and channels 3.0.3 and I am having problems with websockets getting disconnected around 2 seconds after being connected.

This is my consumer and it gets connected but a few seconds later, it disconnects without triggering the disconnect

```
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer
from django.utils import timezone
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class SystemConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    groups = ["WSbroadcast","WSsystemAPP"]

    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        print('Websocket accepted: ' + str(self.scope))

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Called when the socket closes
        print('Websocket disconnected: ' + str(close_code))
```

The asgi file looks like this:

```
import os

import django
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

# Fetch Django ASGI application early to ensure AppRegistry is populated
# before importing consumers and AuthMiddlewareStack that may import ORM
# models.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MainAPP.settings.development")
django.setup()
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator,OriginValidator
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

from MainAPP.consumers import SystemConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Django's ASGI application to handle traditional HTTP requests
    "http": django_asgi_app,

    # WebSocket chat handler
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                url(r"^ws/System/$",SystemConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        )
    ),
})
```

And the JS file looks like:

```
var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
const path = ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + "/ws/System/";
let wsSystem = new WebSocket(path);
console.log("Connecting to " + path);
    
wsSystem.onmessage = function (message) {
    // Handle different actions
    var payload = JSON.parse(message.data);
    if (payload.action == "query_datetime") {
        console.log("System UTC datetime is " + payload.date + " " + payload.time);
    }else if (payload.action == "loading_status") { 
        var loading_status = payload.loading;
        loading(loading_status);
    }else {
        console.log("Unknown action " + payload.action);
    }
};
// Helpful debugging
wsSystem.onopen = function (event) { 
        console.log("Connected to "+path); 
        $("body").removeClass("no_websockets");
        query_system_datetime();
};
wsSystem.onclose = function (event) { 
        console.log("Disconnected to system socket: " + event["code"]); 
        $("body").addClass("no_websockets");
};
    
wsSystem.onerror = function (event) { 
    console.log("Error: " + event); 
    $("body").addClass("no_websockets");
};
```

The JS writes to console that the websockets are connected and a few second later writes disconnected with error code 1011.

Can anyone tell me what can it be failing here?? I guess if the websocket connects, the routing and all the stuff is OK, but it disconnects without any advise...

Should I install uvicorn or similar?? I am on development using WIndows, Eclipse, PyDev...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

It was Redis version on Windows not being upgraded to version 5.

I installed the Redis version 5.0.10 from [here](https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases) and now it connects and stays connected...